# MapBox v10 OnMapClickListener android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am using Mapbox v10 in my application but I can not find the OnMapClickListener function. In v9 we have this function for manage clicking on map :

```
mapBoxMap.addOnMapClickListener(OnMapClicked);
```

But I can not find this function (In java not Kotlin) for version10.
Please help me find the solution.

I found this part of the code that has OnMapClickLinstener but it is in Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
val binding = ActivityViewAnnotationShowcaseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
 
viewAnnotationManager = binding.mapView.viewAnnotationManager
 
mapboxMap = binding.mapView.getMapboxMap().apply {
loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
addOnMapClickListener(this@ViewAnnotationBasicAddActivity)
binding.fabStyleToggle.setOnClickListener {
when (getStyle()?.styleURI) {
Style.MAPBOX_STREETS -> loadStyleUri(Style.SATELLITE_STREETS)
Style.SATELLITE_STREETS -> loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
}
}
Toast.makeText(this@ViewAnnotationBasicAddActivity, STARTUP_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
}
}
 
override fun onMapClick(point: Point): Boolean {
addViewAnnotation(point)
return true
}
```

What is the solution for Java?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

In Mapbox V10 to add OnMapClickListener, we should use GesturesPlugin =>

```
GesturesPlugin gesturesPlugin = GesturesUtils.getGestures(mapView);
gesturesPlugin.addOnMapClickListener(onMapClickListener);
```

In Mapbox V9 to add this method =>

```
mapBoxMap.addOnMapClickListener(onMapClickListener);
```